# Select Pivot table row and columns

Tags: excel, vba, pivot

[image]I need assistance with selecting a Pivot table range to copy into another spreadsheet. What I need to do is copy all the rows and columns for a specific "Project WBS" value that will be searched on.

In my code below I tried using xlDataAndLabel but it only gives me the Project WBS and Pivot Items I need. It leaves out the "Description", "Employee", and "Activity Type" columns. I can't use .EntireRow.Copy because when I go to the other workbook to paste I get an error saying the size is too great.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Max

```
Sub getPivotData()

Dim PvtTbl As PivotTable
Set PvtTbl = Worksheets("Aug 18 Report").PivotTables("PivotTable1")
Worksheets("Aug 18 Report").Activate

Application.PivotTableSelection = True
PvtTbl.PivotSelect "GS136.548", xlDataAndLabel
Selection.Interior.Color = vbYellow
End Sub
```

Comment: Suggested reading: [Referencing Pivot Table Ranges in VBA](https://peltiertech.com/referencing-pivot-table-ranges-in-vba/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try resizing the target label range to the number of columns in the pivottable

e.g.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
    Dim pvt As PivotTable, rng As Range
    Set pvt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)
    With pvt.PivotFields("Project WBS").PivotItems("A").LabelRange
        Set rng = Worksheets(pvt.Parent.Name).Range(.Resize(.Rows.Count, pvt.TableRange1.Columns.Count).Address)
        Debug.Print rng.Address
    End With
End Sub
```

In the following the highlighted area is the address returned by the print statement

[image]

---

Here is an example of referencing the pivot if it is in a different (open) workbook:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
    Dim pvt As PivotTable, rng As Range
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Set wb = Workbooks("Book3.xlsb")
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set pvt = ws.PivotTables(1)
    With pvt.PivotFields("Project WBS").PivotItems("A").LabelRange
        Set rng = ws.Range(.Resize(.Rows.Count, pvt.TableRange1.Columns.Count).Address)
        Debug.Print rng.Address
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This exactly what I need. But how would I copy the data into a variable? @QHarr

Comment: Yes but I'm having a weird error. When I run the macro within the workbook the Pivot table is in. It works great. But I'm actually running the macro from another workbook to search for a value, use that value as the pivot item to get in the pivot table. In this instance the selected text is offset by many rows.

Comment: Then you need to add the workbook reference to the each reference. See edit.